# Kismet API: Curl only device name and MAC address?

Tags: kismet-wireless

Trying to curl the `/devices/... APIs for specific information only. I'm trying the following, without success.

```
http://user:pswd@192.168.1.1:2501/devices/views/all/devices.json -X POST -d 'json={"fields": "[\"kismet.device.base.manuf\", \"kismet.device.base.macaddr\"]" }'
```

Have been trying to follow the docs [here](https://www.kismetwireless.net/docs/devel/webui_rest/commands/)

Comment: Did you ever solve this as I am having the same issue!

Comment: Long ago, but I don't think I did.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me work out how to add fields in the curl request, so any input i would greatly appreciate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565493/unable-to-find-resource-error-from-curl-response